# Install jira connection in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jira

I want to setup Jira connection to my eclipse
My network can't support to setup it from directly download it in eclipse,so I use Offline Installation , download a zip file from atlassian.com and setup it in eclipse.
But it errors,with the information
 ***“(com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.feature.group 3.0.6.v20120628) requires 'org.apache.jasper 0.0.0' but it could not be found”***
How to solve this?Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: have you installed Subclipse or Subversive before that? they are pre-requisites...

Comment: thank you ,but I have installed subclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the subclipse first then atlassian